# CSS rotate3d works correctly only on Firefox

Tags: css, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

The CSS **rotate3d** animation seems to depend on the (modern) browser you use!!! Just test the code...

```
@keyframes KF_Rotate {
                       0% { transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,  0deg); }
                     100% { transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg); }
                     }
.Rotate:hover { animation: KF_Rotate 3s; }
```

How is it possible?

Comment: You should look into browser prefixes. It works in plenty of browsers, even a few old ones.

Comment: I know that browser prefixes are useless in moder (versions of the) browsers. Anyway, I tried, but they don't solve the issue.